# How to deploy spring-boot application with vaadin14 and embedded tomcat on docker from jar and connect to it throught server addres and port?

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker

I'm trying to deploy my application on docker container on ovh server. It works just fine locally but when i open port in firewall and try to connect to it via server address and port it never loads. There are no errors in docker logs of the container and there is no staus code returned in the browser as if the connection nerver happend. The only workaroud i found was **not** to use embedded tomcat, but rather use docker image with tomcat and deploy application from WAR. Still i would like to know why the JAR approach doesn't work for me and what can i try to fix it?

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2.1'

volumes:
  dbbackups:
  postgis-data:
# =====================================================================================
services:
  db:
    image: kartoza/postgis:12.0
    container_name: db
    volumes:
      - postgis-data:/var/lib/postgresql
      - dbbackups:/backups
    environment:
      # If you need to create multiple database you can add coma separated databases eg gis,data
      - POSTGRES_DB=eeradata
      - POSTGRES_USER=application
      - POSTGRES_PASS=password
      - ALLOW_IP_RANGE=0.0.0.0/0
      # Add extensions you need to be enabled by default in the DB. Default are the five specified below
      - POSTGRES_MULTIPLE_EXTENSIONS=postgis,hstore,postgis_topology,postgis_raster,pgrouting
    ports:
      - 25432:5432
    restart: on-failure
    healthcheck:
      test: "exit 0"
# ======================================================================================
  dbbackups:
    image: kartoza/pg-backup:12.0
    hostname: pg-backups
    container_name: dbbackups
    volumes:
      - dbbackups:/backups
    links:
      - db:db
    environment:
      - DUMPPREFIX=PG_db
      - POSTGRES_USER=docker
      - POSTGRES_PASS=docker
      - POSTGRES_PORT=5432
      - POSTGRES_HOST=db
      - POSTGRES_DBNAME=gis
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
# =======================================================================================
  application:
    build: .
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
     - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:13-oracle
#EXPOSE 8081
ADD ./target/application.jar .
CMD java -jar application.jar
```

docker ps:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS                        PORTS                     NAMES
2915972b9b18        kartoza/pg-backup:12.0   "/bin/bash /start.sh"    About a minute ago   Up About a minute             5432/tcp                  dbbackups
964812ab9041        example_application      "/bin/sh -c 'java -j…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute             0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp    example_application_1
050819755d08        kartoza/postgis:12.0     "/bin/sh -c /docker-…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute (healthy)   0.0.0.0:25432->5432/tcp   db
```

Comment: Could you post your dockerfile and docker-compose.yml?

Comment: @MinhDuy sure give me a moment. I will edit post.

Comment: Can you please tell what is OVH?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli https://www.ovh.com/

Comment: @Bankoff docker-compose looks fine. could you post result of `docker ps`?

Comment: @MinhDuy sure give me a sec